# probability of random birthday

Tags: javascript, probability

I am very new to programming in general and Javascript in particular (a couple of weeks) and i am trying to create a program to tell me how many people have to be in a room that it should be probable (more than fifty percent) that one person has the same birthday that I picked beforehand.
the equation in math comes out about 253 people. However after running my program 10000 times it keeps on giving me about 367.I'm wondering if something is wrong with my program or the random number generator on javascript.

```js
//sorry if the code is messy and unprofesional for i am very new 
//functions for specific tasks

const functions = {
        randomGenerator (finish){
            const num = Math.floor(Math.random()*(finish))
            return num;
    } ,
        pickNum () {
        if(check){return}
        check = true;
        chosenTrials = +(prompt("PLEASE ENTER THE AMOUNT OF TRIALS YOU WANT TO RUN."))
        return chosenTrials;
    }
    }
    //The probability of having a person with a specific borthday
    const birthdayBtn = document.getElementById("bdBtn")
    const count = [];
    const dateArray = [];
    let rand;
    let check = false;
    let chosenTrials;
    const date = () =>{
        
        functions.pickNum();
        for(e =0;e<chosenTrials;e++){
            for (let b = 1;b<2000;b++){
                rand =functions.randomGenerator(366);
                if(dateArray.includes(59)){//59 is a random number 
                    dateArray.push(rand);
                    break
                }
            dateArray.push(rand)
               }
               count.push(dateArray.length)
               dateArray.length = 0;
            }
            let avg =  0;
            count.forEach(el => avg+=el)
        
            const final = avg/count.length
            console.log(final)
           // console.log(count)
        
        }
    birthdayBtn.addEventListener('click',date)
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <script src="scripts/statistics.js" defer></script>
        <button id = bdBtn>The birthday problem</button>
       
      </head> 
      <body>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `I'm wondering if something is wrong with my program or the random number generator on javascript.` without looking at your code I'm 100% positive the error is in your program. edit: first error: `functions.pickNum();` needs to be `chosenTrials = functions.pickNum();`

Comment: Also is it "exactly one person" or "at least one person"?

Comment: thank you Chris G. for taking the time to review my code.

Comment: For the first comment, i don't understand why you think that is a problem, for the chosenTrials is initialized in the pickNum method.

Comment: and the second comment, the code automatically breaks when one match is found.

Comment: so i guess it looks for exactly one match.

Comment: True, but that means you can remove `return chosenTrials;`. Where is the `2000` coming from?

Comment: i guess you are right but that is not affecting the answer in any way.The number 2000 is just to make sure that the loop does not finish without a match, for i have done lower numbers and observed that, that happened.

Comment: Here's my version, it confirms 253: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/jezxrf9p/